# Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity runtime error

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I am trying to persist data with Hibernate and I have encountered the following exception during runtime.

Entity Class

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;



@Entity
@Table(name="FINANCES_USER")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private Long userId;

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="BIRHT_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS")
private String emailAddress;

@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
private Date lastUpdatedDate;

@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")
private String lastUpdatedBy;

@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", updatable = false)
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name = "CREATED_BY",updatable = false)
private String createdBy;
```

This is the `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>


    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.codenogo.data.entities.User"/>

</session-factory>
```

This is my main:

```
    public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        User user = new User();
        user.setBirthDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedBy("Arnold");
        user.setEmailAddress("argo@mail.com");
        user.setFirstName("Arod");
        user.setLastName("Nogo");
        user.setLastUpdatedBy("Arno");
        user.setLastUpdatedDate(new Date());

        session.save(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

I have imported `javax.persistence.*` in the `Entity` class. I am not able to persist the data to my database despite having mapped the entity class in the xml config file. I get this exception:

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.codenogo.data.entities.User.`

Any help around this?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate you use? And, please, add `HibernateUtil`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line : `<mapping class="com.codenogo.data.entities.User"/>` from your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file because you are using Annotations to map your entity not the xml mapping mode

Comment: It is not correct. `mapping class` is for a mapping with annotations.

Comment: I'm still encountering the same error. @v.ladynev any thoughts around this?

Comment: @ArnoldNogo Please, do what I asked about in the comment to your question.

Comment: I am using annotated classes therefore needing the     mapping class to specify the class and in this case it is the User class